# how to turn three 1D arrays into one 3D array by calculating the euclidian metric

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three arrays:

```
x_array = [1., 2., 3.]
y_array = [1., 2., 3.]
z_array = [1., 2., 3.]
```

These 3 arrays define the axis for a 3D array. I would like to calculate the Euclidian metric like

```
array3D = np.array((3, 3, 3))
for ix in range(0, 3):
    for iy in range(0, 3):
        for iz in range(0, 3):
            dist = np.sqrt(x_array[ix]**2 + y_array[iy]**2 + z_array[iz]**2)
            array3D[ix][iy][iz] = dist
```

Is there a faster way than three `for` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try broadcasting:

```
a = np.sqrt(np.array(x_array)[:,None,None]**2 
            + np.array(y_array)[None,:,None]**2
            + np.array(z_array)**2
           )
```

Comment: You don't need the leading `None` for `y_array`.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can use `np.add.outer`:

```
np.sqrt(np.add.outer(np.add.outer(x**2, y**2), z**2))
```

Comment: the einsum looks interesting but not sure how to make the euclidian metric working?

Comment: @Carl. Good point. I was so focused on getting the dimensions right, I forgot about your actual question :) will fix momentarily.